# Can I say "sth like a machine adopts advanced technology"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> The equipment adopts advanced technology.

Is the word "adopt" used properly? or is "use" better than "adopt" in this sentence? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adopt) defines **adopt** in this context as:

> to accept or **start** to use something new

Note the emphasis of the word **starts**. If you say that the equipment adopts new technology, you mean that previously it did not use new technology but now it does.

Furthermore, **adopt** suggests **active** acceptance, so you probably could not even use it about a machine that can be reprogrammed with updated software post-manufacture. It might be appropriate for some kind of artificial intelligence system which might be considered sentient, if it actively accepted new technology.

A company can adopt new technology: previously it did not use this new technology, then it started to use it.

If the equipment had this new technology when it was manufactured, you cannot use the word **adopt** because it didn't previously **not** use this new technology.

For technical writing, it would be better to use the word **uses** or **utilises**: for marketing purposes, you could use **exploits** or **takes advantage of**.

Comment: you mean the equipment adopts ...grammatically correct, but the usage is not standard. And if I use adopt, it  indicates that the equipment doesn't use the technology when it was manufactured. Right?

Comment: @Hugege Exactly.